# visualize latent dirichlet allocation results

Tags: graph, visualization, allocation, lda, dirichlet

I'm trying to use Latent Dirichlet Allocation LDA from genism library for Python.
Is there any way to display results of the algorithm over training set in a form of a graph?
Maybe with Venn's diagrams, or some chars?

Answer (score 2):

LDAvis is an excellent tool to visualise LDA results. https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis

Answer (score 1):

I found Jason Chuang's "Termite" visualisation to be quite good.

http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/termite